# Improving the SELECT query performance on a large table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, performance, t-sql, sql-server-2005, query-performance

**Q:** How can I improve the performance of my **queries**?

**Details:** 
I have one table with 200k records `(Sales)` and one function `getView_sls(@TON_orNPS)`

Below query takes **10-12 seconds**

```
SELECT * FROM Sales
```

Below query takes **32-34 seconds**

```
SELECT * FROM getView_sls('TON')
```

Below is my sales table structure:

```
USE [WaterfallDB]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[Sales]    Script Date: 07/09/2013 11:39:17 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sales](
    [year] [varchar](4) NOT NULL,
    [nslschnl] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [distchnl] [varchar](2) NULL,
    [chl6] [varchar](20) NOT NULL,
    [sku] [varchar](15) NOT NULL,
    [ton01] [float] NULL,
    [ton02] [float] NULL,
    [ton03] [float] NULL,
    [ton04] [float] NULL,
[ton05] [float] NULL,
[ton06] [float] NULL,
[ton07] [float] NULL,
[ton08] [float] NULL,
[ton09] [float] NULL,
[ton10] [float] NULL,
[ton11] [float] NULL,
[ton12] [float] NULL,
[nps01] [float] NULL,
[nps02] [float] NULL,
[nps03] [float] NULL,
[nps04] [float] NULL,
[nps05] [float] NULL,
[nps06] [float] NULL,
[nps07] [float] NULL,
[nps08] [float] NULL,
[nps09] [float] NULL,
[nps10] [float] NULL,
[nps11] [float] NULL,
[nps12] [float] NULL,

  CONSTRAINT [PK_Sales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [year] ASC,
    [chl6] ASC,
    [sku] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Below is my function

```
USE [WaterfallDB]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[getView_sls]    Script Date: 07/09/2013 11:55:56 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[getView_sls] (@TON_or_NPS nvarchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN(

SELECT     
dbo.Sales.year, 
dbo.Sales.nslschnl, 
dbo.Sales.distchnl, 

SUBSTRING(dbo.Sales.chl6,12,7) AS chl6, 
BI.dbo.View_ch.chl5, 
BI.dbo.View_ch.chl4, 
BI.dbo.View_ch.chl3, 

dbo.Sales.sku,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.SKU.descr, ISNULL(dbo.Sales.SKU,'Undefined')) AS SKU_descr,
BI.dbo.SKU.bp,
BI.dbo.SKU.ccatg,

SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3) AS phl1,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.phl1.descr, ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3) AS VARCHAR(13)),'Uncategorized')) AS phl1_descr,
SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,4) AS phl2,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.phl2.descr, ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,4) AS VARCHAR(13)),'Uncategorized')) AS phl2_descr,
SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,6) AS phl3,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.phl3.descr, ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,6) AS VARCHAR(13)),'Uncategorized')) AS phl3_descr,
SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,10) AS phl4,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.phl4.descr, ISNULL(CAST(SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,10) AS VARCHAR(13)),'Uncategorized')) AS phl4_descr,
BI.dbo.SKU.phl5 AS phl5,
ISNULL(BI.dbo.phl5.descr, ISNULL(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,'Uncategorized')) AS phl5_descr,

BI.dbo.SKU.crpbrd, 
ISNULL(BI.dbo.crpbrd.descr, ISNULL(BI.dbo.SKU.crpbrd,'Uncategorized')) AS crpbrd_descr,
BI.dbo.SKU.rngbrd, 
ISNULL(BI.dbo.rngbrd.descr, ISNULL(BI.dbo.SKU.rngbrd,'Uncategorized')) AS rngbrd_descr,
BI.dbo.SKU.brdden, 
ISNULL(BI.dbo.brdden.descr, ISNULL(BI.dbo.SKU.brdden,'Uncategorized')) AS brdden_descr,


CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton01 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps01 / 1000000 END AS ton01,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton02 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps02 / 1000000 END AS ton02,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton03 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps03 / 1000000 END AS ton03,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton04 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps04 / 1000000 END AS ton04,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton05 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps05 / 1000000 END AS ton05,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton06 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps06 / 1000000 END AS ton06,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton07 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps07 / 1000000 END AS ton07,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton08 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps08 / 1000000 END AS ton08,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton09 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps09 / 1000000 END AS ton09,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton10 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps10 / 1000000 END AS ton10,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton11 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps11 / 1000000 END AS ton11,
CASE @TON_or_NPS WHEN 'TON' THEN dbo.Sales.ton12 / 1000 ELSE dbo.Sales.nps12 / 1000000 END AS ton12

FROM                
dbo.Sales 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.SKU ON dbo.Sales.sku = BI.dbo.SKU.sku 

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.View_ch ON dbo.Sales.distchnl = BI.dbo.View_ch.distchnl AND SUBSTRING(dbo.Sales.chl6,12,7) = BI.dbo.View_ch.chl6

LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.crpbrd ON BI.dbo.SKU.crpbrd = BI.dbo.crpbrd.crpbrd
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.rngbrd ON BI.dbo.SKU.rngbrd = BI.dbo.rngbrd.rngbrd 
 LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.brdden ON BI.dbo.SKU.brdden = BI.dbo.brdden.brdden
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.phl1 ON SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,3) = BI.dbo.phl1.phl1
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.phl2 ON SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,4) = BI.dbo.phl2.phl2
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.phl3 ON SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,6) = BI.dbo.phl3.phl3
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.phl4 ON SUBSTRING(BI.dbo.SKU.phl5,0,10) = BI.dbo.phl4.phl4
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  BI.dbo.phl5 ON BI.dbo.SKU.phl5= BI.dbo.phl5.phl5  
)
```

Comment: Tip #1: select only what you **really** need - don't just use `SELECT *` for everything. If you limit the columns you retrieve, you're (a) transferring a lot less data, and (b) have the chance to speed a query up by having a **covering index**. With `SELECT *` there's no much you can do....

Comment: @marc_s, thanks I know that one, my queries with * were only examples,  I am looking for configuration tricks, and my possible mistakes in my select query etc.

Comment: 1. How fast is your query if you select an aggregate, like `select count(*) ...`? If you're transferring a ton of data back from the database, the only configuration you can improve on is buying a bigger pipe. Is your network connection big enough? 2. If you're not looking for us to improve select * with no WHERE clause, then post an example query that *is* running slower than expected.

Comment: Maybe the problem is all those joins with substring?

Answer (score 0):

Since 200k records isn't that big and the query takes a long time, you're most likely missing an important index. Either have a clustered index and an identity column or a non clustered index on the columns you are frequently selecting, i.e. `year`.

Also try to explicitly state your column names, `SELECT *` isn't really needed, do you intend to bring back 200k rows each time you run the query?

To create a non clustered index, you can do:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX IX_SALES_Year 
    ON dbo.Sales (Year);
```

You will probably want to apply a few of these and run the query to see which one works the best.  I would also suggest looking at the database tuning wizard, this may provide more of a guide to you.

Comment: my "Year" column is one of my primary keys (together with chl6 & sku fields), so it is unnecessary to make it a non clustered index, isn't it ?, (For SELECT * issue, that is only an example query, I know reducing column names will increase speed, I am looking for configuration tricks, and my possible mistakes in my select query etc.)

Answer (score 0):

First of all if this is my table, I would create a numeric primary key instead of varchar composite clustered index. Remember that non-numeric indexes are always slower then numeric column indexes.

Second, try to create non-clustered indexes on columns used more in your queries, so the good formula is to have on primary numeric index and more non-clustered (numeric or non-numeric) indexes depending on requirement.

Third always avoid partial columns values in joins, that thing work but extremely slows your performance on selects. For this you can create more columns for those values and save while updating or inserting. This would takes mili seconds on update or insert but saves a lot on selecting with full columns name or joining with those column.

These things are always helped me in my 14 years of DB work including very huge tables in Tereadata and SQL Server. I hope these tips will help you and others.